# What is the difference between Rspec have_css, have_selector, and have_field?

Tags: rspec

I have this html.erb Rails form:

```
<h1 class=new_vendor_header>New Vendor Form</h1>

<%= form_for(@vendor) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "ex: Jeff" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This passes:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('input[placeholder="ex: Jeff"]')
```

But this does not:

```
expect(page).to have_field('input[placeholder="ex: Jeff"]')
```

and this does not:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('input[placeholder="ex: Jeff"]')
```

Selector refers to HTML selector right so it refers to html elements?
have_css I thought looked for CSS but it seems to do more. Here is the example from the cheat sheet:

```
response.body.should have_css("input", :count => 3) #True if there are 3 input tags in response
```

And that seems to look for input HTML selectors.

So what is the difference and why do the other two fail in my example?

Comment: Note that `have_css` and `have_selector` aren't part of RSpec itself, but are provided by [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Docs [here](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/capybara/2.0.0/symbols/Capybara::RSpecMatchers/have_css#line=86)  `have_css` will call `has_selector` with `css` as a param, as `has_selector` can handle `css`, `xpath`, ...

```
def have_css(css, options={})
      HaveSelector.new(:css, css, options)
end
```